Synchronize VSCode windows processes
I'm working on an extension that periodically makes requests to an HTTP API. If several VSCode windows are open, they all seem to make such requests which is not optimal.
Therefore I want to make sure that the requests are run in only one place, e.g. in one VSCode window or a global process, and then pushed to the other windows for update of a tree view.
How can this synchronization be done?

VS Code API does not have anything like that, so likely you need to design/implement on your own.

@LexLi. That was also my conclusion. But I'm not sure how to implement that synchronization. I don't find many mechanisms to send messages between VSCode windows. There is SecretStorage, but it's certainly not meant for synchronization.

@LexLi. Do you have any suggestion how to do it? What interprocess communication mechanism would you use?

@LexLi. No solution? Perhaps it wasn't that easy as you thought?

@LexLi. A problem is that most communications, e.g. WebSockets, are server-client, but here all windows are equal. It's not obvious where to run the server.

I have found a way that might work: store data in a file (in the directory given by context.globalStorageUri()) and use fs.watch() to see when it's modified.

@LexLi. A process outside of VSCode that all users of the extension have to start manually? Or should the extension start it from one VSCode window? All windows will then try to start the process.

@LexLi. Considering how "trivial" it is, you seem very unable to show me how to do it.

Implement a Inter Process Communication, Network based. If you start vscode/your extension, check if something is listening on port/socket xyz, if not, start your server, if the port is allready in use, try to connect there. Or implement a "lock file". This is not as hard as it sounds.

As said in my comment, you need to implement a Inter Process Communication (IPC).
The "simplest" way to achieve this, are network sockets.

Start process
Check if pid/lockfile exists
N: Write pid/lock file somehwere
Y: Try to connect to network socket

const { createServer, Socket } = require("net");
const fs = require("fs");
const os = require("os");


const LOCKFILE_LOCATION = `${os.tmpdir()}/my-lockfile.pid`;
const HOST = "127.0.0.5";
const PORT = 9317;


console.log("Started...");
console.log("Check fo lockfile %s", LOCKFILE_LOCATION)


if (fs.existsSync(LOCKFILE_LOCATION)) {

    console.log("Lockfile exists, start in client mode");

    let client = new Socket();

    client.once("close", () => {

        console.log("Socket closed");
        let pid = Number(fs.readFileSync(LOCKFILE_LOCATION, "utf-8"));

        setTimeout(() => {
            try {

                // 0 is a special signal that doesnt actually kill the process
                // process.kill will throw a error
                process.kill(pid, 0); 
                
            } catch (error) {
                if (error.code === "ESRCH") {

                    // process is not running
                    // cleanup & exit or swpan new server here
                    fs.rmSync(LOCKFILE_LOCATION);

                    console.log("Lock/pid file removed");

                    // use a random setTimeout/sleep before creating a new server
                    // the main process part below could be outsourced in a function, which you can call here again

                } else if (error.code === "EPERM") {

                    console.log("process is maybe running");

                } else {

                    console.error("Could not check if main process is running", error);

                }
            }
        }, 100);

    });

    client.on("data", (data) => {
        console.log("data from main/server process", data.toString());
    });

    client.connect(PORT, HOST);

} else {

    console.log("Lockfile does not exists, start in server mode");

    // store the PID in the lockfile to check if the process is running on exit
    // if not, delete the lockfile
    fs.writeFileSync(LOCKFILE_LOCATION, `${process.pid}`);

    let server = createServer();

    server.on("connection", (socket) => {

        socket.write(`Hello client, server here ${process.pid}. You want some http requests data?`);

    });

    // 127.0.0.5 used on purpose
    server.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
        console.log(`Server listening on tcp://${HOST}${PORT}`);
    });

}

The example above is not perfect, but a good starting point for you the get the concept.
E.g. what happens when the main process/vs code window is closed, but the others are still open? Then you could create a new network socket. Be careful to not try to create multiple sockets. To avoid this, a random sleep/setTimeout could be used.
You see, there are more things to keep in mind when working with IPC.
EDIT: To show better how a sync is done, i modified the code above a bit.
    let server = createServer();
    let clients = new Set();

    // this simulates your http/api requests
    // unref is used that the process exits
    setInterval(() => {

        console.log("Broadcast data to %d clients", clients.size);

        let data = JSON.stringify({
            boolean: true,
            timestamp: Date.now(),
            string: "Hello Client"
        });

        Array.from(clients).forEach((socket, i) =>{
            socket.write(data, () => {
                console.log("Data writen to client #%d", i);
            });
        });

    }, 5000).unref();

    server.on("connection", (socket) => {

        console.log("Client connected");

        socket.once("close", () => {

            console.log("Client disconnected");
            clients.delete(socket);

        });

        socket.write(`Hello client, server here ${process.pid}. You want some http requests data?`);
        clients.add(socket);

    });

Instead of the setInterval do your HTTP Requests there, and when you received your needed data, send that over the network socket to all connected clients.

So the synchronization is here basically done using a file (the lockfile)?

Is sync per se is done via a network socket, In you main process (where the tcp server is created) do your HTTP API requests, and send them to all connected clients. This is your synchronization. The lockfile is just there to tell the other VS Code Windows if they should be start as clients and connector to the server or start the start.

@md2perpe I updated the code to show better how a sync could be done.

@md2perpe Do you have any question about the code or is it clear how to send the data from the server (main window) to clients?

I understand how the code works. The process that is first on the ball tells the other processes "I do it" by creating the lockfile and then starts the server. The other processes then connect to the server to get data from that. If the server or the process starting it exits or dies, the first process that notices should start a new server. There are some gaps that could result in a race condition; if that is a problem some mutex should be used.

@md2perpe If this a solution you can work with, please mark it as it.
